# Get parent Enumeration of Value typetag

Tags: scala, reflection, types, runtime, scala-reflect

I have a [`Type`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types$Type.html) instance that refers to the `Value` of a specific `Enumeration`.

Is there any way to get the `Type` or `Symbol` of the parent enum? In other words, if I have `typeOf[SomeEnumeration.Value]` how can I obtain `typeOf[SomeEnumeration]`?

I know this information exists at runtime because I can see it in the debug console with `valueType.pre.sym`, but I can't come up with a public API for accessing it in code.

My first thought was `valueType.typeSymbol.owner`, but this just gives the `Symbol` for the base class `Enumeration`, not the specific enumeration instance that I want.

Comment: Can you add some simplified code sample to illustrate your problem and make it easier to reproduce and test.

Comment: @michaJlS There's not much to add in the way of code. I have `typeOf[SomeEnumeration.Value]` (where `SomeEnumeration` is not directly known) and I need `typeOf[SomeEnumeration]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an enumeration

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

Then try to match against `TypeRef`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

typeOf[WeekDay.Value] match {
  case TypeRef(pre, _, _) => pre // WeekDay.type
}
```